# 'Se è una constatazione è surreale' vs. 'Se è una constatazione, è surreale'

Tags: orthography, punctuation

Un tizio mi ha detto

> È una constatazione.

e io ho risposto

> Se è una constatazione è surreale.

Secondo voi sarebbe necessario, o anche solo opportuno, mettere una virgola dopo 'constatazione', o la frase sta bene come è?

Comment: Opportuno forse, necessario no.

Comment: Se non altro, è opportuno perché aumenta la leggibilità della frase, seppur di poco.

Answer (score 2):

Trattandosi di una subordinata ipotetica, la virgola è quantomeno opportuna e direi fortemente consigliata.

> Se non metti la virgola, ti vengo a cercare a casa

Se qualcuno chiede citazioni nei commenti, bisogna accontentarlo. Gabrielli nel suo "Come parlare e scrivere meglio" (un libro che ho letto ma che chiaramente non ho interiorizzato) scrive (pag. 84) che la virgola è appunto opportuna (e fortemente consigliata) per separare diverse proposizioni all'interno del periodo.

Nel paragrafo sul periodo ipotetico, solo un esempio su sette non contiene la virgola. Ecco perché scrivo "opportuna e fortemente consigliata" invece che "obbligatoria".

Comment: Puoi portare qualche fonte, per piacere?

Comment: @DaG Grazie per aver corretto, in questo modo non sembro un analfabeta (nota come evito di usare accenti in questo commento) :-)

Comment: Figurati, sono un pignolo intrinseco. (Scrivere senza usare mai accenti potrebbe essere un esercizio simile al lipogramma...)

Comment: @astabada : FYI, puoi digitare molti caratteri accentati usando il layout di tastiera "US International".

Comment: Grazie mille sia a DaG per il lipogramma, che non conoscevo, sia a Giulio Muscarello per il layout "US international".